# How long should I wait for priming solution to mix when added to a keg?

Tags: bottling, corny-keg, priming

**Background**

After my beer reached FG I transferred it into a corny keg, cold crashed in my keezer at 42°F, and fined with gelatin.  48 hours after adding the gelatin I pulled about a pint of sludge until the beer was looking clear.

I'd like to add priming solution to the beer and bottle straight from my corny keg in a few days.

**Questions**

1. If I pour my priming solution into the top of the keg, will it mix effectively so that I'm not left with varying amounts of carbonation in each bottle (or perhaps even bottle bombs)?
2. How long should I allow the keg to sit to ensure the priming solution has mixed completely?
3. I'll be keeping the keg at 42°F prior to bottling, which I assume means the yeast (Wyeast Irish Ale - 1084) will be dormant and won't start working on the priming sugar until I've bottled the beer and warmed it up.  Is that a safe assumption?

**Notes**

- Each time the keg has been opened it has been sealed and purged with 15PSI and then taken off gas.  I assume this has added a negligible amount of CO2 that can be ignored for priming calculations.

**UPDATE (3 weeks later)**

Carbonation levels appear to be consistent on bottles filled at both the beginning and end of the keg.  Only 1 of ~10 random bottles sampled seemed different (slightly over-carbed).

I did exactly as @jsolarski recommended and gently poured the priming solution into the keg, sealed and purged, gave it a gentle shake/roll, and bottled after a few minutes.

In the future I will do multiple gentle rolls and wait at least 15 minutes to ensure thorough mixing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1) yes it will mix, give it a good shake or stir or swirl

2) as little as 5 mins, but would not let it sit over night.

3) temperature is no guarantee, unless below freezing, that your yeast will be fully dormant. you can be safe to assume that the yeast will be very slow, and eat the sugars at a very low rate

** remember to take temperature into account when adding your priming solution.

also if you Fined your beer, it may take longer to carbonate in bottles due to less yeast floating around.  so a good swirl would be recommended

Comment: I mixed in the solution, gave it a little bit of a shake/roll, and bottled right from the keg – I'll update in a few weeks with results.